# iOS/Restore issue

Tags: iphone, ios, restore

I wanted to run something by an expert before I tried this. So if I was to update an iPhone from iOS 9 to iOS 10, would I be able to restore the now-updated iPhone to iOS 9 using an iCloud backup? Or would I need to revert it to iOS 9 via .jpsw before being able to restore the phone's data?

Comment: *9.3.5. They stopped signing .4 a couple of weeks ago. @Tetsujin

Comment: oops, yup. There were so many in quick succession I lost track ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot restore to a prior version of the OS. The backup only contains your data, it does not contain the OS itself.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Would I be able to restore it after reverting the iOS using the .ipsw?